# CRM 2011 - Record is Unavailable suddenly appears on some Entities

Tags: iis, crm

We are having a serious problem on the new "CRM 2011"-server.  We recently migrated from the CRM 4.0 to the CRM 2011.  I've imported all the old "CRM 4.0"-DB's to the new CRM 2011. All the organizations are working fine. We have ADFS configured on the Server, so that we have IFD enabled on all the Organizations.

We have 8 customers on the new server, who are using the same "Entities"-structure.  We have for ex. "Trainings" & "Registrations" on Organization A, B & C.

Suddenly the "Trainings" on organization "A" doesn't work anymore.  When we do "New" or we try to open an existing record, we are getting the "Record Is Unavailable" error. We are getting the same error on the "Registrations" on entity "B".  Suddenly the "Trainings" are working again on the "A", but then it doesn't work on "B" anymore.  Or both are working again... So there is something weird going on.

When I do an "IISRESET", everything is working again and we can open "Trainings" & "Registration" on both "A" & "B" & "C".

Do you have any Idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this problem, but the bug still remains.  I will report this bug to Microsoft, hoping that this bug will be solved in a new CRM 2011 ROLLUP.

The workaround is :

- Open the "Edit" Main Form
- Hit the "Save As"-button on the "Edit" Main form and give it a appropiate name
- Remove all the "Security Roles" on the old Main Form
- Add all the needed "Security Roles" on the new Main Form
- Publish The entity and It should work again

Hope that this will help other people!